# Datepicker and Timepicker not initialised when the test runs

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, angular-test

In my Angular app, I often use the [datepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker) and the [timepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/timepicker) components from [ngx-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap).

They work great, however apparently I'm unable to test them. The problem is that when my test case is running, those components are not initialised yet:

[image: first line debugger]

I set the breakpoint on the first line of my test case.

When the test case finishes to execute, I can see that the datepicker and timepicker components are correctly initialised:

[image]

My code is the following:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MyComponent,
        // ...
      ],
      imports: [
        BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
        TimepickerModule.forRoot(),
        // ...
      ],
      providers: [
        // ...
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.autoDetectChanges(true);
  });

  it('some expectation here', () => {
    // whatever I put here, at this line the datepicker and timepicker will NOT be initialised
  });
});
```

how can I make my test case run **AFTER** that the datepicker and timepicker components have been initialised?

---

**EDIT**:

I did more investigations, the issue is about the `[(ngModel)]="time"` of the `<timepicker>` element
basically it's being triggered only AFTER my test case exits.

how can I manually trigger it?

I tried with `timepickerElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));` but it doesn't work.

also tried `fixture.detectChanges()`, `fakeAsync`+`tick()`, etc... but couldn't solve the issue.

Comment: Please add related code in your question.

Comment: @AmitChigadani I can add the code but as I mentioned, I set the breakpoint on the first line of my test case and the widgets are not initialised... that is the issue.

Comment: @AmitChigadani I added the code

Comment: Did you try `fixture.detectChanges();` instead of `fixture.autoDetectChanges(true);`?

Comment: @AmitChigadani yes I'm already using that

Comment: I would wrap the function within `it()` with `fakeAsync()` and execute `tick()` so that everything settles into place before testing.

Comment: @dmcgrandle I've just tried that and doesn't solve the issue :(

Comment: @FrancescoBorzì hmmm ... can you put this all in a StackBlitz?  I'll fork it and play around with a few ideas if you do so.  If you don't have a starter project in Stackblitz, feel free to fork [this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53437297?file=app%2Fcalculate.component.spec.ts) and replace the info with your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the `[(ngModel)]` directive for Datepicker and Timepicker was triggering only after that the test case was executed (because I'm wrapping them into a custom component that then it's used as a form control).

To trigger that, I needed to add:

```
datetimeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
timepickerElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
fixture.detectChanges();
```

after changing the values of the Datepicker and Timepicker elements.